# How to display data from different table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
Table 1
| ID | Post_Name  | Post_Status | Parent_ID | Post_Content | Post_Type |
+----+------------+-------------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
| 1  | John Sample| publish     | 0         | Content Text | person    |
| 2  |            | inherit     | 1         | image1.jpg   | attachment|
| 3  |            | inherit     | 1         | image2.jpg   | attachment|
| 4  |            | inherit     | 1         | image3.jpg   | attachment|
| 5  | Mark Sample| publish     | 0         | Mark  Text   | person    |
| 6  |            | inherit     | 5         | image1.jpg   | attachment|
| 7  |            | inherit     | 5         | image2.jpg   | attachment|
| 8  |            | inherit     | 5         | image3.jpg   | attachment|

Table 2
| meta_id | post_id  |    meta_key    |      meta_value       |
+---------+----------+----------------+-----------------------+
|   1     |    1     |  Address       | Sample Street,Country |
|   2     |    1     |  Phone         | 10000000000000        |
|   3     |    1     |  Sex           | Male                  |
|   4     |    1     |  Primary pic   | 2                     |
|   5     |    2     |  Thumbnail     | John_thumbnail.jpg    |
|   6     |    2     |  meta_data     | data_data_data        |
|   7     |    5     |  Address       | Mark Street,Country   |
|   8     |    5     |  Phone         | 20000000000000        |
|   9     |    5     |  Sex           | Male                  |
|   10    |    5     |  Primary pic   | 6                     |
|   11    |    6     |  Thumbnail     | Mark_thumbnail.jpg    |
|   12    |    6     |  meta_data     | data_data_data        |
```

**I would like to display like this**

Name: John Sample
Comment: Content Text
Address: Sample Street, Florida
Phone: 10101010101010
Sex: Male
**Thumbnail: John_thumbail.jpg**
Photo: images1.jpg, images2.jpg, images3.jpg

Name: Mark Sample
Comment: Mark Text
Address: Mark Street, Florida
Phone: 20101010101010
Sex: Male
**Thumbnail: Mark_thumbail.jpg**
Photo: images1.jpg, images2.jpg, images3.jpg

[image: see how the thumbnail links]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  t.Post_Name AS Name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN t2.meta_key = 'Address' THEN t2.meta_value END) AS 'Address',
  MAX(CASE WHEN t2.meta_key = 'Phone' THEN t2.meta_value END) AS 'Phone',
  MAX(CASE WHEN t2.meta_key = 'Sex' THEN t2.meta_value END) AS 'Sex',
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.Post_Content  SEPARATOR ',') AS Photo
FROM Table1 p
INNER JOIN table1 t ON p.parent_ID = t.ID
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t.Id = t2.post_id
GROUP BY p.Post_Name;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ca7b/8)

This will give you:

```
|        NAME |               ADDRESS |          PHONE |  SEX |                            PHOTO |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| John Sample | Sample Street,Country | 10000000000000 | Male | image3.jpg,image2.jpg,image1.jpg |
```

---

Then using PHP, you can display them the way you want.

---

### Update

If you want to display the value of `user comment` as comment, you can do this:

```
SELECT
  t.Post_Name AS Name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN t2.meta_key = 'Address' THEN t2.meta_value END) AS 'Address',
  MAX(CASE WHEN t2.meta_key = 'Phone' THEN t2.meta_value END) AS 'Phone',
  MAX(CASE WHEN t2.meta_key = 'Sex' THEN t2.meta_value END) AS 'Sex',
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.Post_Content  SEPARATOR ',') AS Photo,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.post_Content) comment
FROM Table1 p
INNER JOIN table1 t ON p.parent_ID = t.ID
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t.Id = t2.post_id
GROUP BY p.Post_Name;
```

### [Updated SQL fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ca7b/10)

---

### Update2:

Based on the updated sample data:

```
SELECT
  p.Post_Name AS Name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN t.meta_key = 'Address' THEN t.meta_value END) AS 'Address',
  MAX(CASE WHEN t.meta_key = 'Phone' THEN t.meta_value END) AS 'Phone',
  MAX(CASE WHEN t.meta_key = 'Sex' THEN t.meta_value END) AS 'Sex',
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.Post_Content  SEPARATOR ',') AS Photo,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.post_Content) comment
FROM
(
  SELECT *
  FROM Table1 
  WHERE parent_id = 0
) AS p
INNER JOIN table1 AS c ON p.ID      = c.parent_ID
INNER JOIN table2 AS t ON t.post_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.post_Name;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69f05/14)

This will give you:

```
|        NAME |               ADDRESS |          PHONE |  SEX |                            PHOTO |      COMMENT |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| John Sample | Sample Street,Country | 10000000000000 | Male | image2.jpg,image1.jpg,image3.jpg | Content Text |
| Mark Sample |   Mark Street,Country | 20000000000000 | Male | image3.jpg,image1.jpg,image2.jpg |   Mark  Text |
```

---

### Update 2

For the updated data, try this:

```
SELECT 
  t1.*,
  t2.meta_value AS 'Thumbnail'
FROM
(
  SELECT
    p.Post_Name AS Name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t.meta_key = 'Address' THEN t.meta_value END) AS 'Address',
    MAX(CASE WHEN t.meta_key = 'Phone' THEN t.meta_value END) AS 'Phone',
    MAX(CASE WHEN t.meta_key = 'Sex' THEN t.meta_value END) AS 'Sex',
    MAX(CASE WHEN t.meta_key = 'Primary pic' THEN t.meta_value END) AS 'Primary_pic',
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.Post_Content  SEPARATOR ',') AS Photo,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.post_Content) comment
  FROM
  (
    SELECT *
    FROM Table1 
    WHERE parent_id = 0
  ) AS p
  INNER JOIN table1 AS c ON p.ID      = c.parent_ID
  INNER JOIN table2 AS t ON t.post_id = p.id
  GROUP BY p.post_Name
) AS t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2  ON t1.Primary_pic = t2.post_id
                     AND t2.meta_key = 'Thumbnail';
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb016/11)

This will give you:

```
|        NAME |               ADDRESS |          PHONE |  SEX | PRIMARY_PIC |                            PHOTO |      COMMENT |          THUMBNAIL |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| John Sample | Sample Street,Country | 10000000000000 | Male |           2 | image3.jpg,image1.jpg,image2.jpg | Content Text | John_thumbnail.jpg |
| Mark Sample |   Mark Street,Country | 20000000000000 | Male |           6 | image1.jpg,image2.jpg,image3.jpg |   Mark  Text | Mark_thumbnail.jpg |
```

---

---

### Update 3

For this new `meta_data` column you will need one more join to the second table as we did for the `primary pic` like this:

```
SELECT 
  t1.Name,
  t1.Address,
  t1.Phone,
  t1.Sex,
  t1.Photo,
  t1.Comment,
  t2.meta_value AS 'Thumbnail',
  t3.meta_value AS 'meta_data'
FROM
(
  SELECT
    p.Post_Name AS Name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t.meta_key = 'Address' THEN t.meta_value END) AS 'Address',
    MAX(CASE WHEN t.meta_key = 'Phone' THEN t.meta_value END) AS 'Phone',
    MAX(CASE WHEN t.meta_key = 'Sex' THEN t.meta_value END) AS 'Sex',
    MAX(CASE WHEN t.meta_key = 'Primary pic' THEN t.meta_value END) AS 'Primary_pic',
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.Post_Content  SEPARATOR ',') AS Photo,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.post_Content) comment
  FROM
  (
    SELECT *
    FROM Table1 
    WHERE parent_id = 0
  ) AS p
  INNER JOIN table1 AS c ON p.ID      = c.parent_ID
  INNER JOIN table2 AS t ON t.post_id = p.id
  GROUP BY p.post_Name
) AS t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2  ON t1.Primary_pic = t2.post_id
                     AND t2.meta_key = 'Thumbnail'
INNER JOIN table2 t3  ON t1.Primary_pic = t3.post_id
                     AND t3.meta_key = 'meta_data';
```

### [Like this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4c45/3)

This will give you:

```
|        NAME |               ADDRESS |          PHONE |  SEX |                            PHOTO |      COMMENT |          THUMBNAIL |      META_DATA |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| John Sample | Sample Street,Country | 10000000000000 | Male | image1.jpg,image2.jpg,image3.jpg | Content Text | John_thumbnail.jpg | data_data_data |
| Mark Sample |   Mark Street,Country | 20000000000000 | Male | image2.jpg,image3.jpg,image1.jpg |   Mark  Text | Mark_thumbnail.jpg | data_data_data |
```

Comment: What's an `INNER JOIN`? Is it different from a `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: @Cobra_Fast: About joins http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/

Comment: @Cobra_Fast `Join`s are either `INNER` or `OUTER`(`LEFT`, `RIGHT` or `FULL` ) and (`cross` ). Inner joins will get only those matched rows based on the join condition. However, the outer join will  be include those unmatched rows, in case of `LEFT` those from the left table. In case of `RIGHT` those of the right joined table. For instance, in the query I posted if a post from the table name has no entry in the table2 it won't be listed using this query, but using `LEFT JOIN` will include it but with `NULL` value of the data coming from the other table `talbe2` since it has no entries there .

Comment: i update the question on result: please review again. thanks for help

Comment: @Mahmoud Gamal: please the "post_content" column is not separate actual the images is echo one by one and  "post_content" column is also mix content of images link and text comment of user.

Comment: @Mahmoud Gamal: one last thing please. again the column "post_content" have value of images link and user comment text. i would like it to display that value "Content text" as comment and images as photo. is that possible? that is on one column "post_content"

Comment: @user1999747 - Sorry for late, my appologies I was out of here :( . See my edit.

Comment: @user1999747 Can you please show me some more sample data with this issue, Please try to update [**this demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ca7b/10) with more entries explaining the issue.

Comment: @Mahmoud Gamal: sorry now i edit my post.. i add more entry user so you will understand.. thanks for help

Comment: @user1999747 Its OK, See my edit. Try it. If you need any thing else don't hesitate to ask any time. Sorry, but I have to go. I will be back some hours later.

Comment: @Mahmoud Gamal: hi, can i ask a help again? im having problem with this. I update the Post Question and i did add some Thumbnail data. As you can see the in table 2 the meta_key(Primary pic) the value is link to Table 1 ID and it link back to Table 2 as post_id for Thumbnail value. Please help me. thanks

Comment: @Mahmoud Gamal:  please please :(

Comment: @user1999747 First of all, I am so sorry for late, I am on work right now and I couldn't respond to you. See my edit, my **udpate 2**. Is is right? and sorry again for late

Comment: @Mahmoud Gamal: sorry for disturbing you :( .. i am so thankful with your help and i also badly needed to solve this :( .. sorry but its not working on me. no data will display.. actually on table 2 the value of Primary pic is also used twice as a post_id: as you can see post_id(2) = Thumbnail and another post_id(2) = meta_data: now i want only  the value of  Thumbnail will incloud on table result at the last column( this should be a John_Thumbnail and Mark_thumbnail).. Thank you so much.. and sorry again :( im so happy you help me

Comment: @user1999747 - There is no disturbing at all, so please stop saying this. But, Sorry I couldn't understand this last one; how `thumbnail` relates to `meta_data`? Are you looking for displaying this `meta_data` with the others like [in this demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4c45/2)? Please edit your question and show me the exact result you want in this case. Thanks.

Comment: @Mahmoud Gamal: the result should be as what ive post on my question: meta_data is just a sample only of many data . i want only to get thmbnail pic. the table result will like this:  NAME-->ADDRESS--->PHONE--->SEX--->PHOTO--->COMMENT--->THUMBNAIL :D thank you

Comment: @user1999747 So you need to get all the meta keys as columns headers no matter how many they are? right. But Is there any metakeys that relates to other parents in the same time like `primary pic`? Is there any keys like this?

Comment: @Mahmoud Gamal: no no, i dont want to all meta keys as column headers... your last edit is already fine.. but just remove the primary_pic column on your query result. i having only difficult to understand because gzzzz.. hard to explain.. ok wait i will draw a graph :D

Comment: @Mahmoud Gamal: i added a graph on my post question,  please review and thanks.. your last 2 edit is fine already just add that result or are that in last column of result as thumbnail

Comment: @user1999747 OK, see my update 3, not sure if this is what you are looking for, or I am missing something. please review it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code

```
SELECT    Table1.ID,
Table1.POST_NAME,
Table1.Post_Status,
Table1.Parent_ID,
Table1.Post_Content,
Table1.Post_Type,
Table2.meta_id,
Table2post_id,  
Table2meta_key,
Table2.meta_value       
FROM TABLE2,TABLE1
WHERE TABLE1.id= TABLE2.post_id
```

Comment: i update the question on result: please review again. thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I would look into JOINS in SQL so something like this:

```
SELECT post.post_name, 
       phone.meta_value 
FROM   table_1 AS post 
       LEFT JOIN table_2 AS phone 
              ON post.id = phone.id 
                 AND phone.meta_key = "phone"
```

edit as needed.

Comment: can you code in specific from selecting to display? thank you

Comment: Only things under Select will be returned. If that's what you mean.